# Changing many column types in r with purrr

Tags: r, purrr

`str(mtcars)`

How do I make a list of some column names and change them to numeric or character. For example say I want to change `c("am", "gear")` into character columns.

I am looking for a solution e.g. with purrr; I know how to do it manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't necessarily need `purrr` in this case. You can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

mutate_at(mtcars, c("am", "gear"), as.character)
```

Comment: @ Jake: Thanks, I did not think about that!

Comment: @ Jake: Can see if there is an error in the following: ``mutate_at(c("a", "b"), as_datetime(as.numeric(), origin="1960-01-01 00:00:00 UTC"))`` ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want really purrrfect ;) method:

```
mtcars <- modify_at(mtcars, c("am", "gear"), as.character)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need `dplyr` in this case. You can use `base R`:

```
cols <- c("am", "gear")
mtcars[cols] <- lapply(mtcars[cols], as.character)
```